# biblatex with ieee style not working anymore (biblatex-ieee)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, ieee-style

I have a problem with my bibliography. After updating all packages with MikTeX, `biblatex` throws errors. I have uninstalled and installed MikTeX and Texmaker several times, this did not help. After a closer look I think I found the source of the problem. They have released an update of the [`biblatex-ieee`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ieee) package, and it seems that it does not work properly anymore.

```
% not working anymore, with the latest version of biblatex-ieee package
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex} 
! Package biblatex-ieee Error: Failed to update citation style.See the biblatex-ieee package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... ...p,cite:comp:end,cite:comp:inset,cite:dump}

% what's working
\usepackage[style=ieee-alphabetic]{biblatex}
```

So my question: Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

I was thinking of installing the old version of the package, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: a new biblatex-ieee has been sent to ctan, but miktex seems not to have it yet. You could download the files from ctan https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-ieee and put them in your document folder until miktex updates the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the information @Ulrike Fischer, i didn't notice that the miktex version (1.3b) is not the latest version of ctan (1.3c). As solution i downloaded the newest files from ctan and overwrote the older files located in my miktex installation. Now everything works as expected again.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed in the latest release of `biblatex-ieee`., [v1.3c](https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-ieee/releases/tag/v1.3c). The change relates to updates to `biblatex` itself, rather than to anything in `biblatex-ieee`. Moreover, only yhe citation style is affected: your bibliography will continue to work even if you have not updated to v1.3c.

---

For the present, you could add

```latex
% The second step is to replace \multicitedelim and
% \multicitesubentrydelim with a version wrapped in
% the appropriate delimiter.
\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
  \expandafter\patchcmd\expandafter
    {\csname abx@macro@\detokenize{#1}\endcsname}%
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\bibclosebracket\multicitedelim\bibopenbracket}
    {}
    {%
      \PackageError{biblatex-ieee}{Failed to update citation style}\@ehc
    }%
  }
\docsvlist{cite:comp:end,cite:comp:inset,cite:comp:shand,cite:dump}

\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
  \expandafter\patchcmd\expandafter
    {\csname abx@macro@\detokenize{#1}\endcsname}%
    {\multicitesubentrydelim}
    {\bibclosebracket\multicitesubentrydelim\bibopenbracket}
    {}
    {%
      \PackageError{biblatex-ieee}{Failed to update citation style}\@ehc
    }%
  }
\docsvlist{cite:comp:inset,cite:dump:inset}


% There's also one \multiciterangedelim and one
% \multicitesubentryrangedelimto alter.
\expandafter\patchcmd\expandafter
  {\csname abx@macro@\detokenize{cite:dump}\endcsname}%
  {\multiciterangedelim}
  {\bibclosebracket\multiciterangedelim\bibopenbracket}
  {}
  {%
    \PackageError{biblatex-ieee}{Failed to update citation style}\@ehc
  }%

\expandafter\patchcmd\expandafter
  {\csname abx@macro@\detokenize{cite:dump:inset}\endcsname}%
  {\multicitesubentryrangedelim}
  {\bibclosebracket\multicitesubentryrangedelim\bibopenbracket}
  {}
  {%
    \PackageError{biblatex-ieee}{Failed to update citation style}\@ehc
  }%
```

after loading `biblatex` to get the right behaviour: you'll still have the warning at point-of-loading, but the output would be fixed.